# Getting NSInternalInconsistencyException during iOS app runtime

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, applepay

I recently migrated my app from `Xcode 7` to `Xcode 8` after upgrading the code base from `Swift 2` to `Swift 3`. The app compiles fine but during runtime I am getting following exception.

No idea what needs to be done here.

**Exception:**

```
2016-09-14 14:00:16.098 ApplePaySwag[5762:122585] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7fb361823600; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; 
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000049f60>; 
layer = <CALayer: 0x608000035100>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 665}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<ApplePaySwag.SwagListViewController: 0x7fb3614068e0>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050dd34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104a5f21e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050e1442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
//code removed for brevity
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**SwagListViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SwagListViewController: UITableViewController  {

    var swagList = [
        Swag(   image: UIImage(named: "iGT"),
                title: "iOS Games by Tutorials",
                price: 54.00,
                type: SwagType.Electronic,
                description: "This book is for beginner to advanced iOS developers. Whether you are a complete beginner to making iOS games, or an advanced iOS developer looking to learn about Sprite Kit, you will learn a lot from this book!"),

     // code removed for brevity

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SwagCell

        let object = swagList[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = object.title
        cell.priceLabel.text = "$" + object.priceString
        cell.swagImage.image = object.image
        return cell
    }

   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
           let object = swagList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]
        (segue.destination as! BuySwagViewController).swag = object
       }
   }

}
```

**SwagCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SwagCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var swagImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: What's your code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Did you register your cell in code? In Storyboard ?

Comment: Just updated my question with some more code so that you can get better insight

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, not yet..

Comment: You might find your answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157812/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource-with-swift-3

Answer (score -1):

You might find your answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/40157812/

"error occurs because the signature of cellForRowAtIndexPath is wrong. In Swift 3 it's

```
(override) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and use the convenience method

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath)
```

which returns always a valid non-optional cell."