# failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource with swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have the below UITableViewController attached as a searchResultsController:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {
    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(matchingItems.count)
        return matchingItems.count
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image][image]

Here it crashed once `matchingItems.count` is no equal to 0 for example:

> 0 0 10 2016-10-20 15:43:53.914 ios-App[9137:977735] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UITableView.m:8035
>   2016-10-20 15:43:53.927 ios-App[9137:977735] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0,
>   -64}; contentSize: {768, 440}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

When I add debugging points witin cellForRowAtIndexPath they are never reached, the app seems to crash before this point?

Comment: A couple of things to check: 1) Make sure the data source of the table view is correctly set to the view controller. 2) Make sure you have registered your cells with the table view so they can be dequeued correctly.

Comment: thank you @dlbuckley I have updated the question

Comment: @dlbuckley If the `UITableViewController` is designed in Interface Builder – as it is obviously –  you don't need to register the cell nor set `delegate` and `datasource` programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error

> failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

occurs because the signature of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is wrong. In Swift 3 it's

```
(override) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and use the convenience method

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath)
```

which returns always a valid non-optional cell.

---

PS: You don't need to set datasource and delegate to `self` because `UITableViewController` does that implicitly

Comment: Another problem. The call to `dequeueReusableCell` can return `nil`.

Comment: `(override) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` gives me an error (`expected declaration` and `consecutive declarations must be separated by ';'`). Xcode 8.1.

Comment: @afkatja I put `override` in parentheses. If the target class is `UITableViewController` you need `override`, if the the target class is `UIViewController` you don't need it. Remove the parentheses and follow the suggestion of the compiler, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue! After several minutes of debugging, I realized I didn't inherit the

> UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

on my ViewController.